# SMART Pre-fail (Temperature 70)

Tags: disk, temperature, fsck, smart

Could someone please interpret the SMART Data and Self-tests using Disks in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

The other day all of a sudden I started receiving errors upon every command entered into the terminal, I restarted and everything has been working fine.

Yet, SMART tests reveals this:

[DISK is OK (Temp 30, Threshold not exceeded, All values 100 except Temperature is 70(pre-Fail)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2gtk.png)

It's and SSD disk I've been using for 8 months. Is it about to fail? Everything seems to be working fine.

Fsck from live CD indicates the disk CLEAN.

Thank you.
Using Lenovo z51-70, i5, Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Pre-fail is the *type* of the indication ( as opposed to just an indication of how old the drive is ), its current status is OK.